# How is it possible to remotely access photos on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, security, photos

Is there any software to do so, and what would it take to install it?
Another person had physical access to my phone, so I suspect the possibility of installation of such software.
Even photos which I immediately deleted and those, which went straight to application got in other hands.

I have an iPhone 4s. It was not jailbroken (at least, by me), and it did not appear such: no Cydia app or other oddities.
Photo Stream and iCloud backup for photos were also off, and I never used them.

Comment: 'got out'? You mean they were published somewhere online? If they had your phone & full access to it, they could have used your own email or any type of 'share' to send them to anywhere, without installing anything.

Comment: @Tetsujiin Clarified that.

Comment: There are many ways it could be done without any additional software. One thing you should do immediately is change your AppleID password.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, that's what I did. Can you please explain more?

Comment: open Photo, pick any picture, tap the Share button bottom left - that's how many options there already are to send the pic from your device without the need to install further software

Answer (score 1):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/289), [Google+](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509?hl=en-GB) and other similar apps offer the ability to automatically upload new photos to your cloud storage. Do you have anything like that installed?

Comment: No, nothing like that.